# Analyzing json columns in mysql using Drill or Presto

Tags: apache-drill, presto

I have a sharded table with one pk column and a text column. The text column holds an object in json format. I want to enable ad hoc business analytics by using drill or presto.

Just experimented with both but i am unable to figure out how to parse the json and access its fields in a query.

For drill i tried `convert_from(features,'JSON')` and for presto i tried `json_parse(features)`. Both seem to convert column text to JSON as a simple select but i cannot access object fields in the same query.

Performance is important so need to avoid io, open to options requiring development effort or hardware scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to analyze json column in presto by using `json_extract_scalar` on output of `json_parse` ex. `json_extract_scalar(json_parse(features),'$.r_id')`. This returns me a string which i can cast to required data type.